# Mod_security problem in whm/cpanel/wordpress

Tags: php, cpanel

i have updated my cpanel and then i try to upload any media in wordpress im getting the error

"**Post-processing of the image failed likely because the server is busy or does not have enough resources. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels.**"

so then i changed .htaccess file and add this code for single cpanel

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

so my error is fixxed but i want to do it for all the cpanel (hosting provider) can someone tell me how to do it for all the cpanel havinf 2000+ cpanel :(